# C++ call of overloaded class constructor is ambiguous

Tags: c++, overloading

I know similar questions have been asked before. However, I don't see why this is ambiguous.

I'm making a class `foo` and want to either give it a vector or multiple values. But my compiler doesn't like it. Why is this the case?

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class foo
{
public:
        foo(std::vector<int> dims) { }
        foo(int s1, int s2) { }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        foo<double> x({7,3});
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you want to use your template parameter somewhere, like I dunno, wherever you have `int` now?

Comment: I'd like to be able to put either `foo<double> x({3,7})` or `foo<double> y(3,7)`

Comment: `foo<double> x{ { 7,3 } };` for the vector constructor, but I think you missed my point. Why is it a template when you're not using the template parameter.  Like did you want a vector of doubles or ints?

Comment: I'm using `https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler` which uses g++ as the backend

Comment: @RetiredNinja I want it to be a vector of `int`s. The initializer is the size of an N-D array. But the code compiles fine when I comment out `foo(int s1, int s2) { }`

Comment: @user1543042 you should [edit] with the error message you get. If you read the error message, I think what is ambiguous is pretty clear

Comment: Replacing `std::vector<int>` with `std::initializer_list<int>` seems to work. Maybe the constructor for `std::vector<int>` that can take two arguments  (count and value [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)) is being considered by the compiler?

Comment: @crayzeewulf not really, note that replace `foo(int,int)` (and this is what keeps the semantics) have the same result.

Comment: Hmm. I was afraid of that but did not get to try it out. I guess we are back to square one.

Comment: @appleapple, using `initializer_list` does appear to work but is not the ideal solution. See [this](https://ideone.com/bNBLDv) for example. Basically, `foo<double> y(3, 7)` calls `foo(int, int)` but `foo<double> y {3, 7}` calls `foo(const std::initializer_list<int>&)`. This interface is bound to be confusing the user.

Comment: @crayzeewulf if you replace `foo(int, int)` instead of `foo(std::vector<int>)` like what I reply to you, then it is not the biggest problem, I don't really know what's your point, though. I'm just correct your comment. I'd personally not use it. And I've give a (IMHO) correct answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Because your class have compiler generated copy/move constructor.

---

So your have the duplicates for

```
foo(const foo&)  // foo can be constructed by {7,3}
foo(vector<int>) // vector<int> can be constructed by {7,3}
```

---

Maybe you are trying to do [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), but your syntax is not correct.

There is no `T object({arg1, arg2, ...})`

But if you use `foo x{7,3}` (which matches the `T object{arg1, arg2, ...}`), it would work and call `foo(int,int)`.

---

BTW, you should learn and always **read the error**, at least on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AAundMRt4NcL18m1), the error is pretty clear

> error: call of overloaded 'foo()' is ambiguous ...
>
> note: candidate: 'foo::foo(std::vector)'
>
> note: candidate: 'constexpr foo::foo(const foo&)'
>
> note: candidate: 'constexpr foo::foo(foo&&)'

It **clearly** shows what it thinks is candidate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't explicitly told the compiler which one you are trying to call here. If you want to call the constructor that is passed a vector you need to explicitly tell the compiler that.
You can use direct list initialization:

```
foo<int> x(std::vector<int>{ 7,3 });
```